# pip-reviewで正常にアップデートできない

Tags: ubuntu, pip, wsl

`$ pip-review --auto` を実行してもアップデートできません（？）
エラー内容としては、subprocess-exited-with-errorとでています。
あと、wheelが正しく実行できてない？感じです。一応 `pip install wheel -U` は実行しました。
すみません。初心者なものでこれ以上はわかりません。

## 出力

```bash
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: blinker in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (1.4)
Collecting blinker
  Using cached blinker-1.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (2023.5.7)
Collecting certifi
  Using cached certifi-2023.7.22-py3-none-any.whl (158 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (3.1.0)
Collecting charset-normalizer
  Using cached charset_normalizer-3.2.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (201 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: comm in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (0.1.3)
Collecting comm
  Using cached comm-0.1.4-py3-none-any.whl (6.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: contourpy in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.0.7)
Collecting contourpy
  Using cached contourpy-1.1.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (300 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (3.4.8)
Collecting cryptography
  Using cached cryptography-41.0.3-cp37-abi3-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (4.3 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: dbus-python in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (1.2.18)
Collecting dbus-python
  Using cached dbus-python-1.3.2.tar.gz (605 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [30 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ol2zwg0d/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 1047, in wrapper
          return func(*args, **kwargs)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ol2zwg0d/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 1091, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          with _project(config_settings) as project:
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
          return next(self.gen)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ol2zwg0d/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 985, in _project
          with Project.with_temp_working_dir(
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
          return next(self.gen)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ol2zwg0d/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 831, in with_temp_working_dir
          yield cls(source_dir, tmpdir, build_dir, meson_args, editable_verbose)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ol2zwg0d/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 652, in __init__
          _check_meson_version()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ol2zwg0d/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 1026, in _check_meson_version
          meson_version = subprocess.run(['meson', '--version'], check=False, text=True, capture_output=True).stdout
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 503, in run
          with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1863, in _execute_child
          raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
      FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'meson'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

## 環境

- WSL on Ubuntu

  - VERSION="22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
- Windows 11 Home

  - ver: 22H2

```bash
Package                  Version
------------------------ -------------
asttokens                2.2.1
attrs                    23.1.0
backcall                 0.2.0
blinker                  1.4
certifi                  2023.5.7
charset-normalizer       3.1.0
cmake                    3.27.2
comm                     0.1.3
command-not-found        0.3
contourpy                1.0.7
cryptography             3.4.8
cycler                   0.11.0
dbus-python              1.2.18
debugpy                  1.6.7
decorator                5.1.1
distro                   1.7.0
distro-info              1.1+ubuntu0.1
et-xmlfile               1.1.0
exceptiongroup           1.1.3
executing                1.2.0
filelock                 3.12.3
fonttools                4.39.4
graphviz                 0.20.1
gyp                      0.1
htmlmin                  0.1.12
httplib2                 0.20.2
idna                     3.4
ImageHash                4.3.1
importlib-metadata       4.6.4
ipykernel                6.25.1
ipython                  8.15.0
ipywidgets               8.0.6
japanize-matplotlib      1.1.3
jedi                     0.18.2
jeepney                  0.7.1
Jinja2                   3.1.2
joblib                   1.2.0
jupyter_client           8.2.0
jupyter_core             5.3.0
jupyterlab-widgets       3.0.7
keyring                  23.5.0
kiwisolver               1.4.4
launchpadlib             1.10.16
lazr.restfulclient       0.14.4
lazr.uri                 1.0.6
lit                      16.0.6
MarkupSafe               2.1.2
matplotlib               3.6.3
matplotlib-inline        0.1.6
more-itertools           8.10.0
mpmath                   1.3.0
multimethod              1.9.1
nest-asyncio             1.5.6
netifaces                0.11.0
networkx                 3.1
numpy                    1.23.5
nvidia-cublas-cu11       11.10.3.66
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu11   11.7.101
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11   11.7.99
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11 11.7.99
nvidia-cudnn-cu11        8.5.0.96
nvidia-cufft-cu11        10.9.0.58
nvidia-curand-cu11       10.2.10.91
nvidia-cusolver-cu11     11.4.0.1
nvidia-cusparse-cu11     11.7.4.91
nvidia-nccl-cu11         2.14.3
nvidia-nvtx-cu11         11.7.91
oauthlib                 3.2.0
openpyxl                 3.1.2
packaging                23.1
pandas                   1.5.3
parso                    0.8.3
patsy                    0.5.3
pexpect                  4.8.0
phik                     0.12.3
pickleshare              0.7.5
Pillow                   9.5.0
pip                      22.0.2
pip-review               1.3.0
platformdirs             3.5.1
prompt-toolkit           3.0.38
psutil                   5.9.5
ptyprocess               0.7.0
pure-eval                0.2.2
pydantic                 1.10.7
Pygments                 2.15.1
PyGObject                3.42.1
PyJWT                    2.3.0
pyparsing                2.4.7
python-apt               2.4.0+ubuntu2
python-dateutil          2.8.2
pytz                     2023.3
PyWavelets               1.4.1
PyYAML                   5.4.1
pyzmq                    25.0.2
requests                 2.28.2
scikit-learn             1.2.2
scipy                    1.9.3
seaborn                  0.12.2
SecretStorage            3.3.1
setuptools               59.6.0
six                      1.16.0
stack-data               0.6.2
statsmodels              0.13.5
sympy                    1.12
systemd-python           234
tangled-up-in-unicode    0.2.0
threadpoolctl            3.1.0
torch                    2.0.1
torchview                0.2.6
torchvision              0.15.2
torchviz                 0.0.2
tornado                  6.3.2
tqdm                     4.64.1
traitlets                5.9.0
triton                   2.0.0
typeguard                2.13.3
typing_extensions        4.7.1
tzdata                   2023.3
ubuntu-advantage-tools   8001
ufw                      0.36.1
unattended-upgrades      0.1
urllib3                  1.26.15
visions                  0.7.5
wadllib                  1.3.6
wcwidth                  0.2.6
wheel                    0.37.1
widgetsnbextension       4.0.7
ydata-profiling          4.1.2
zipp                     1.0.0
```

## 追記

- pip, settooltip, wheelを最新に引上げした後に`pip-review --auto`

```shell
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: dbus-python in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (1.2.16)
Collecting dbus-python
  Using cached dbus-python-1.3.2.tar.gz (605 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [94 lines of output]
      + meson setup /tmp/pip-install-o9wc7pf0/dbus-python_98410d1529654481814aa55f32d594f5 /tmp/pip-install-o9wc7pf0/dbus-python_98410d1529654481814aa55f32d594f5/.mesonpy-czhj9p13/build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=/tmp/pip-install-o9wc7pf0/dbus-python_98410d1529654481814aa55f32d594f5/.mesonpy-czhj9p13/build/meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.2.1
      Source dir: /tmp/pip-install-o9wc7pf0/dbus-python_98410d1529654481814aa55f32d594f5
      Build dir: /tmp/pip-install-o9wc7pf0/dbus-python_98410d1529654481814aa55f32d594f5/.mesonpy-czhj9p13/build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: dbus-python
      Project version: 1.3.2
      C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 9.4.0 "cc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0")
      C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.34
      Host machine cpu family: x86_64
      Host machine cpu: x86_64
      Compiler for C supports arguments -fno-common: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-missing-field-initializers: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-declaration-after-statement: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-inline: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-redundant-decls: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-switch-default: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-write-strings: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wcast-align: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wdouble-promotion: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wduplicated-cond: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wfloat-equal: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat-nonliteral: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat-security: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat=2: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Winit-self: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wlogical-op: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-declarations: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-format-attribute: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-include-dirs: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-noreturn: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wnull-dereference: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wpacked: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wpointer-arith: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wshadow: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wswitch-enum: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wundef: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wunused-but-set-variable: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wjump-misses-init: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-prototypes: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wnested-externs: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wold-style-definition: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wpointer-sign: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wstrict-prototypes: YES
      Configuring _dbus-python-config.h using configuration

      Executing subproject dbus-gmain

      dbus-gmain| Project name: dbus-gmain
      dbus-gmain| Project version: undefined
      dbus-gmain| C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 9.4.0 "cc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0")
      dbus-gmain| C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.34
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -fno-common: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-missing-field-initializers: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wcast-align: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wdouble-promotion: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wduplicated-branches: YES
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wduplicated-cond: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wfloat-equal: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat-nonliteral: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat-security: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat=2: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Winit-self: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wlogical-op: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-declarations: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-format-attribute: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-include-dirs: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-noreturn: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wnull-dereference: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wpacked: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wpointer-arith: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wredundant-decls: YES
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wshadow: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wswitch-default: YES
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wswitch-enum: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wundef: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wunused-but-set-variable: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wwrite-strings: YES
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wdeclaration-after-statement: YES
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wjump-misses-init: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-prototypes: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wnested-externs: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wold-style-definition: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wpointer-sign: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wstrict-prototypes: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (0.29.1)
      dbus-gmain| WARNING: Found CMake '/home/desert/.local/bin/cmake' but couldn't run it
      dbus-gmain| Found CMake: NO
      dbus-gmain| Run-time dependency dbus-1 found: NO (tried pkgconfig)

      ../../subprojects/dbus-gmain/meson.build:107:11: ERROR: Dependency "dbus-1" not found, tried pkgconfig

      A full log can be found at /tmp/pip-install-o9wc7pf0/dbus-python_98410d1529654481814aa55f32d594f5/.mesonpy-czhj9p13/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

## お詫び

コメント頂いたkunifさんには大変申し訳ないのですが、いろいろ試してみてどうにもならなかったので、ubuntuの環境を一から書き直すことにしました。

Comment: 関係無いかもしれませんが、`pip`, `setuptools`, `wheel`の3つが最新版では無いようなので、先ずはその3つだけを最新版に更新してから`pip-review --auto`してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 違うモジュール(pydbus) [\[Ubuntu 20.04\] Unable to "Build from Source": dbus-python is DEPRECATED #1089](https://github.com/kliment/Printrun/issues/1089), [Using dbus to poweroff...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59434149/9014308) 古いPython版数 [how to install dbus-python?](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/12v5gbw/how_to_install_dbuspython/) 追加Ubuntuパッケージ [pip failed to install dbus-python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56123942/9014308), [Can't install dbus-python on Ubuntu...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60444193/9014308), [dbus-python...](https://wiki.onakasuita.org/pukiwiki/?dbus-python) 等

Comment: 単に検索して関連してそうなものを紹介しているだけなのでそんなに手間では無いですが、元々何のために何をしようとしているのかを見直してみた方が良いかもしれません。問題の切っ掛けとなっている dbus 関連の説明には非推奨とか代替方法は...とかが良く出てくるので、今から使うのに必要なのか？元々の目的のためには別の手段が有るのでは？といったことを考えることもアリだと思われます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(WSL上の Ubuntuや pip-reviewを扱ったことがないので, 正しくないかもしれませんが ・・・)

その Ubuntuが素の Ubuntuとほぼ同じであるのなら
素の Ubuntuでは ([venv](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/venv.html)などの仮想環境なしに) pipを直接動かしたりしません
OSを構成する一部のコマンドは Pythonで作製されており 下手にパッケージを更新するとシステムに悪影響を及ぼす危険性がでるから

なので仮想環境を使います。主な種類は以下に

- [venv --- 仮想環境の作成](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/venv.html)
- [Pipenv: 人間のためのPython開発ワークフロー](https://pipenv-ja.readthedocs.io/ja/translate-ja/)
- [Poetry: Python packaging and dependency management made easy](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry)

(個人的には Anaconda3の Condaも使ってる)

---

pip-reviewが pipの使い勝手をよくした中身が pipとほぼ同じ, ならば
まずは仮想環境用意すべきかもしれません

Answer (score 1):

一からやり直して、それで直るのならそれで良いと思いますが、基本的には出ているエラーを読み、一つ一つ対処することになります。下では追記の方のエラーのみ触れます。

#### エラーメッセージが伝えていること

- CMakeが `/home/desert/.local/bin/cmake` で見付かったが動かない
- dbus-1 が見付からない
- 完全なログは `/tmp/pip-install- ... /meson-log.txt` に有る

該当する箇所:

```
      dbus-gmain| WARNING: Found CMake '/home/desert/.local/bin/cmake' but couldn't run it
      dbus-gmain| Found CMake: NO
      dbus-gmain| Run-time dependency dbus-1 found: NO (tried pkgconfig)

      ../../subprojects/dbus-gmain/meson.build:107:11: ERROR: Dependency "dbus-1" not found, tried pkgconfig

      A full log can be found at /tmp/pip-install-o9wc7pf0/dbus-python_98410d1529654481814aa55f32d594f5/.mesonpy-czhj9p13/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
      [end of output]
```

#### 対処

完全なログを読むことから始めるのが良いかも知れませんが、大まかには以下のような対処が考えられます。

- CMake: 他の依存関係のエラーを解決しても直らない場合は、`~/.local/bin/cmake` を実行してみるなどして、動かない原因を調査する必要が有ります。
- D-Bus: おそらく、Ubuntuのパッケージ `dbus` か `libdbus-1`、`libdbus-1-dev` あたりが依存関係を満たすでしょう。